# validates_presence_of and with templates ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, templates

I'm trying to validate some ratio buttons making sure the user as selected one of them. I do this by using:

```
validates_presence_of
```

In addition, I have specific template that I use for the page's layout.  Normally, without the template layout, The anything that is missing is highlighted automatcially by the validates_pressense_of helper in red.  However, with with the template, I only see the displayed words which is probably a result of the template.

Is there some way fix this and have the missing fields highlighted in red with the template?

Here is the snippet of the .css file i'm using for the template:

```
body{


background:#F4DDB1;


margin:0;
font: 10pt/14pt 'Lucida Grande', Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
}

A:link{ color:#275A78; text-decoration:none; }
A:hover{ color:#333333; text-decoration:underline; }
A:active{ color:#275A78; text-decoration:none; }
A:active:hover{ color:#333333; text-decoration:underline; }
A:visited{ color:#275A78; text-decoration:none; }
A:visited:hover{ color:#333333; text-decoration:underline; }

#header{
background:url(../images/headerbg.gif) no-repeat #F4DDB1 top left;
width:282px;
height:439px;
margin-right:auto;
/*
 *margin-left:0;
 */
margin-bottom:0;
text-align:right;
float:left;
}

#wrap{
width:782px;
margin-right:auto;
margin-left:auto;

}

#container{
background:#F8EBD2;
width:500px;
/*margin-left:282px; 
margin-top:-452px; */
float:right;
}

#navcontainer{

/*
 * 
 */position:absolute;
   width:282px;

   margin-right:auto;
   margin-top:435px;
   margin-left:60px;

}

#navlist li{
    margin-left:15px;
   list-style-type: none;
   text-align:right;
   padding-right: 20px;
   font-family: 'Lucida Grande', Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   font-size:12px;
   color:#666666;
}

#navlist li a:link { color: #666666; text-decoration:none; }
#navlist li a:visited { color: #999999; text-decoration:none; }
#navlist li a:hover {color: #7394A0; text-decoration:none; }

h3{
font-size:21px;
font-weight:bold;
color:#8C7364;
}

.content{
padding:10px;
width: 100%
text-align:justify;
font: 9pt/14pt 'Lucida Grande', Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#footer{

  background:transparent;

   height:66px;
   text-align:center;
   font: 8pt/14pt 'Lucida Grande', Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   color:#333333;
}

#title{
position:absolute;
top:440px; 
left:9px;
padding-left:9px;
font: 14pt/12pt 'Lucida Grande', Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
color:#275A78;
}
```

The code will be in this portion:

```
<div class="content">

           <!-- here is your page content -->
                <%= yield :layout %>
           <!-- end page content -->

           </div>
```

http://www.otoplusvn.com/TherapistSurvey/counselor_questionaries/new

If you don't click on any radio buttons, and press submit you only see the error messages, but the fields aren't highlighted.

Any Advise appreciated,
Thanks,
Derek

Answer (score 0):

The highlights from Rails comes from CSS that targets :

`.field` and `.field_with_errors`

These classes are generated with the following HAML in Rails :

```
.field
  = f.label :type
  = f.check_box :type
```

In HTML :

```
<% form_for(@plant) do |f| %>
 <%= f.error_messages %>
 <b>Plant Name</b>
 <p>
 <%= f.label :name %><br />
 <%= f.text_field :name %>
..
```

What does your HAML look like for say, one of your fields?

Comment: Please look at the answer above.  I answered with the question so You could see the html code used to generate the radio button.  It's a snippet of code, not the full source.

Answer (score 0):

```
<table  cellpadding ="5" cellspacing="3" width="100%">
        <% for rating_option in [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]  -%>
        <td align ="center">          
               <%= radio_button("counselor_effectiveness", category, @temp[rating_option])%>
        </td>
        <% end -%>
 </table>
```

I'm still really new to css and ruby on rails.  The above code is used to generate the radio buttons.  Are you saying that in the css i can control the color of the background of the radio buttons (being highlighted) through the css?  If so , how is that done?

Thanks,
D

Comment: Is that an asnwer to your original question? Yes, CSS will be responsible for the change in color, and Rails will be responsible for the logic that identifies if something is an error or not. Assuming you didn't start this project, the way errors are handled in this application may have been altered, or handled differently all together. Are there other snippets of code that have error validation in them that work? If so, paste those, and we'll compare.

Comment: The only validation that is done is through the validate_presense_of through the model in ruby on rails.  No addition error handling was done.

If that snippet of code is what produces the radio buttons that I want to be highlighted, how do I use CSS to control how it is highlighted?  Currently, if you click on the link in the initial posted question, you'll see the box not being hihglighted when the submit button is clicked.  If i remove the template, you'll see the highlighted fields.  I actually took the css from an open source.